# SQL Select Where Between statement missing results that should be there?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I apologize if this question has already been asked, but I couldn't find anything on it.

Basically, my accounting department runs a report every month to pull up all orders from a specific client for the previous month. My problem is that I have orders that are not showing up in these reports. The only similarities I can find in the orders that are missing is that if there are 2 or more sequential order numbers, one or more of them will not be picked up by the report if most other fields are the same.

When I ran the report over a single 24 hour period, any orders that were missing from the month-long report would show up for that day.

This is the code I'm using for the query:

```
SELECT paydetail.ord_hdrnumber as ord_hdrnumber,
    NULL As TotalRevenue,
    paydetail.pyt_itemcode As Item,
    NULL As ItemRevenue,
    pyd_amount As ItemPay,
    paydetail.asgn_type,
    paydetail.asgn_id, ord_driver1,
    ord_revtype1, pyt_description As ItemDesc,
    pyt_basis As ItemBasis
FROM paydetail 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN payheader ON pyh_pyhnumber = pyh_number
    JOIN orderheader on orderheader.ord_hdrnumber = paydetail.ord_hdrnumber
    JOIN paytype on paytype.pyt_itemcode = paydetail.pyt_itemcode
WHERE ord_billto = @billto
    AND ord_startdate BETWEEN @startdate + ' 00:00:00' AND @enddate + ' 23:59:59'
    AND paydetail.pyt_itemcode NOT IN ('TCKEVE','TCKEXP','TCKDEB')

UNION ALL

SELECT invoicedetail.ord_hdrnumber as ord_hdrnumber,
    ivh_totalcharge As TotalRevenue,
    invoicedetail.cht_itemcode As Item,
    ivd_charge As ItemRevenue,
    NULL As ItemPay,
    NULL As asgn_type,
    NULL as asgn_id,
    NULL as ord_driver1,
    ord_revtype1,
    [cht_description] As ItemDesc,
    [cht_basis] As ItemBasis
FROM invoicedetail
    LEFT OUTER JOIN invoiceheader ON invoiceheader.ivh_hdrnumber = invoicedetail.ivh_hdrnumber
    JOIN orderheader on orderheader.ord_hdrnumber = invoicedetail.ord_hdrnumber
    JOIN chargetype ON chargetype.cht_itemcode = invoicedetail.cht_itemcode
WHERE ivh_billto = @billto 
    AND ord_startdate BETWEEN @startdate + ' 00:00:00' AND @enddate + ' 23:59:59'
ORDER by ord_hdrnumber
```

Comment: FYI I always use `>= @startdate` and `< dateadd(day, 1, @enddate)`.  If it is at all possible that you have an order at 23:59:59.230 then the between would miss it.

Comment: Can you give an example data item that does not show up? Is `@startdate` a datetime? Do your results make sense if ord_startdate is treated as a string?  I.e. looking between '9/1/2016' and '9/31/2016' would fail if comparing as strings and ord_startdate is '9/5/2016' or something.

Comment: Can you include the declarations of your variables and how they get assigned?

Comment: Variables are assigned by user input into  form field. The query runs from a web interface built in VBNet. '@startdate' and '@enddate' are both datetimes, with '@startdate' being the first date the user enters for the report and '@enddate' being the last date users enter for the report. As for orders that don't show up, 250540 shows, and 250541 doesn't. 250681 shows but 250682 doesn't. 250767 shows but 250766 and 250768 don't.

Comment: Also, I use between because the orders are entered by customers during work hours, and the startdate is when the materials get picked up from a dock during working hours. But I'll keep the >= < functions in mind for other applications.